# Method References in VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way or plugin to display the references on top of a method declarations in `VsCode`? Something similar to Visual Studio reference display?

Comment: For which language? For C# and TypeScript it already does that: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_reference-information

Comment: @UnholySheep I use vsCode for Angular and TypeScript.

Comment: Then you probably just need to enable it *"by setting `"typescript.referencesCodeLens.enabled": true` in the User Settings file."*: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_references-codelens

Comment: @UnholySheep Yep, that did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This feature is called a code lens and must be implemented per-language by extensions.

VS Code's built-in JavaScript and TypeScript extension includes support. To enable this, just [set](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

- `"javascript.referencesCodeLens.enabled": true`
- `"typescript.referencesCodeLens.enabled": true`

The C# extension enables references code lenses by default. The setting for this is:

- `"csharp.referencesCodeLens.enabled": true`

Comment: Can you also specify where exactly these configurations are to be set?

Comment: Please specify, exactly where the configuration has to be set.

Comment: In VS Code -> ctrl + shift + p and type `open user settings (json)`

Answer (score 3):

Screen shot and process below for mac user, but should be somewhat similar to other platform

Go to Code > preferences > setting

and search `referencesCodeLens` in search then enable like below screenshot.

[image]

Once Done you should see the no of reference above the method name

[image]